# Need text at the same height in all the divs

Tags: html, css

I am using angular and bootstrap4, I have few rows inside the divs 
How do I keep **line1 text** always at the same height so that if any div has a **line0** then all the **line1 text** in all divs will go down and remain always in the same line? 
[image]

```
<div *ngFor="let account of clientAccounts" >

          <h6 class="card-title customCardTitle">{{ account.number }}</h6>

          <h1 class="card-subtitle"> {{ account.cash }} </h1>

       </div>
```

so if account.number has more then 0 lines then account.cash is not aligned horizontally , this is what I am missing.

.customCardTitle has `white-space: pre-line`

at the end I need to prevent this, and keep cash information in the same line
 [image]

Comment: could you post a sneak peek of this code?

Comment: give same class to every line 1 and check the position of line relative to the box dynamically and get higher distance and put it

Comment: You will have to do this thorugh JS I think... But please, give us some code :)

Comment: Here is a post with something similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19695784/how-can-i-make-bootstrap-columns-all-the-same-height.  Also, I solved my issue like this using bootstrap card decks without a title. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/card/#card-decks

Comment: So, correct me if im wrong... But if account.number is more than one object, then show account.cah... And account.cash should always be on the same height inside the div, lets say bottom..?

Comment: @Kalabalik you are correct

Comment: Wouldn´t a solution be to have the .cash on bottom always?...

Comment: @Kalabalik partially yes, but then divs must have also the same size, so if one will have more text and will resize, the other should too.

Comment: That will Bootstrap do for you.. Just wrap the divs in a row and then class them col.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.wrap{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: stretch;
}
.card{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 400px;
    background: gray;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 20px;
    color: #FFF;
}
.card-title{
    flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">

    <div class="card">

      <h6 class="card-title customCardTitle">AT0080456789 (Aco)</h6>

      <h1 class="card-subtitle">$ 1,557</h1>

   </div>

   <div class="card">

      <h6 class="card-title customCardTitle">AT0080456789 (Aco) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
      tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</h6>

      <h1 class="card-subtitle">$ 2,357</h1>

   </div>

   <div class="card">

      <h6 class="card-title customCardTitle">AT0080456789 (Aco) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
  tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquaLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
  tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquaLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
  tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</h6>

      <h1 class="card-subtitle">$ 557,256</h1>

   </div>

</div>
```

Comment: no way, this looks ok in  your example only because you set hight to 30 px, if you put more text it will overflow, but it should extend each divs.this is not a solution

Comment: I've just updated my answer, no fixed height anymore.

Answer (score 3):

Bootstrap `row` will contain `flex` property. With that only we can able to use `flex` properties for child `divs`

> `align-items-center` will center the content inside `cols`

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row align-items-center">
    <div class="col-3"><span>test</span></div>
    <div class="col-3"><span>test</span></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now code will center the text vertically, But within the container height. It won't be center to your html page.

To make Your text to center of your page, make row div to full height `100vh`

Comment: @Kalabalik Actually it need to b align vertically form coding prospective form UI it is horizontally aligned

Comment: Ether way, the centering was not part of the question..?

Comment: Well in that case as he update his question rather then align item center use align item space between.. as he can play with flex align properties